# Not getting back email from Facebook OAuth API, Passport with MEAN Stack

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mean-stack, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

I'm working to set up Face book OAuth for user logging into my website. I am getting an object back from Facebook with my FB information but there is no sign of email anywhere in that profile response.

When I click the  "Login to Facebook" button on my page it takes me to Facebook and says the app will require my profile and email as I added email to the scope of things I wanted. Here is my code:

config/routes.js:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope:['email']}));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', 
{ successRedirect: '/confirm_community',
  failureRedirect: '/signin' }));
```

==============
passport.js

```
 passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    // pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
    clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL

},

function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
     process.nextTick(function() {
            console.log(profile);
            // console.log(profile.emails[0].value);
             User.findOne({'facebook.id':profile.id}, function (error, result){
                    if(error){
                        return done(error);
                    }
                    if(user) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    }
                    else {
                        var newUser = new User();
                        newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
                        newUser.facebook.token = accessToken;
                        newUser.facebook.name = profile.displayName;
                        newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                        newUser.save(function (error){
                            if(error){
                                console.log(error);
                                throw error;
                            } else {
                                return done(null, newUser);
                            }
                        });
                    }
             });
        });
}));
```

Here is the FB object I get back when I console.log(profile) in the process.nextTick function with FB's response:

```
{ id: 'my id is coming back here',
  username: undefined, (because I don't have one)
  displayName: 'my name is coming back here',
  name:
   { familyName: undefined, (I don't have any of these in my profile)
     givenName: undefined,
     middleName: undefined },
     gender: undefined,
  profileUrl: undefined,
  provider: 'facebook',
  _raw: '{"name":"my name is coming here","id":"my id is coming here"}',
  _json: { name: 'my name is coming here', id: 'my id is coming here' } }
```

I made sure my email is public and login to Facebook normally with my email and password, so I'm not using Mobile Phone to sign to Facebook. I'm just missing that email address. I can't seem to figure out why that object isn't giving me back an email?? What am I missing? Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I find another solution for this issue with PASSPORT-FACEBOOK node module. Hope this will help others.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
  profileFields: ['email']
```

Ref : https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/129

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Declarative Fields" in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

You now have to specify the fields you want to get in the API call: `/me?fields=name,email`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I now have this:  app.get('/auth/facebook/me?fields=name,email', passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email']}));  but I am getting a 'Cannot GET /auth/facebook' error message when clicking on the "Login with Facebook" button.....do I need anything like this in my FB button -scope="email,user_birthday,user_about_me"..? Or would I have to delete the app and create a new one with this change?

Comment: that is a weird api endpoint you are trying to use...make sure you authorize first, and then use the /me endpoint separately. and make sure you know how login with facebook works: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.4

Comment: Yeah figured I was using that incorrectly. The FB Docs talk about 'Steps for Using Facebook Login With the JavaScript SDK' but that seems like a completely different approach then the one I am using. I'm assuming the way I'm doing it is alright since I am at least getting back the FB object. Maybe thats incorrect. When you say authorize first, are you referring to authorizing them with FB and my app, and once the response comes back use the /me endpoint in the process.nextTick function? Thanks again for the help.